# Listview loading large lists very slowly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a WPF application that searches through a large data set and displays the results in a `ListView`.  The search can return a small result set, or the result set can be thousands of items.  Searching the data set and returning the result set takes less than a second.  The return set is an `ObservableCollection`.  My `ListView` is slow when it's being loaded.  The `ListView` is bound to the `ObservableCollection` in the XAML.  This is the XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="Translations" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,0,10,8">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FoundItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              MaxHeight="2000"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Translation File Name" Width="NaN" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="English" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=English}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="International" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=International}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
      <Grid Margin="5,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Search English" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchEnglish}" />
        <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Content="Search International" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchInternational}" />
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

This is the view model property to which the `ListView` is bound:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataAccess.TranslationItem> FoundItems
{
  get
  {
    return p_FoundItems;
  }
  set
  {
    p_FoundItems = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange("FoundItems");

    TranslationsFound = string.Format("{0} translations found", p_FoundItems.Count);
  }
}
```

This is the code that builds the FoundItems collection.  It takes just a few ms to execute and build the collection.  The speed issue is definitely not located here.  It is using a black box DLL to get the list.  It then builds a collection of items that can be used in the ObservableCollection.

```
public List<TranslationItem> SearchList(bool fCaseSensitive, bool fIgnoreAmpersands, bool fExactMatch,
                                        string sSearchLanguage, string sSearchString)
{
  List<TTranslations.TranslationItem> lstFound = null;
  List<TranslationItem> lstReturn = new List<TranslationItem>();

  p_trItems.SearchingFile += p_trItems_SearchingFile;

  lstFound = p_trItems.SearchList(fCaseSensitive, fIgnoreAmpersands, fExactMatch, sSearchLanguage, sSearchString);

  foreach (TTranslations.TranslationItem tiItem in lstFound)
    lstReturn.Add(new TranslationItem(tiItem));

  return lstReturn;
}
```

In the view model, I have the following code that is responsible for setting FoundItems.  It casts the collection returned to an ObservableCollection.

```
  FoundItems = new ObservableCollection<DataAccess.TranslationItem>(p_trItems.SearchList(p_fCaseSensitive, p_fIgnoreAmpersands, p_fExactMatch, p_fSearchEnglish ? "E" : "I", p_sSearchString));
```

A breakpoint before and after this line of code indicates that FoundItems takes mere milliseconds to build.

Any idea why it would be loading so slowly?  This is a conversion from an older application where I'm building the list manually, in a loop, and that takes only a second or two load.

Comment: How do you update the `FoundItems` property? If you clear it and add the items in a loop that would not be surprising.

Comment: FoundItems is a property on the view model that exposes the collection.  Building the collection takes less than a second.

Comment: Building it is not the issue, the method you posted creates a `List` not an observable collection. The question is whether you trigger *n* view updates by adding the items individually or whether you have one assignment only.

Comment: I updated the question.  I am casting the List returned from SearchList to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: That's not a cast. Anyway, that should be not be the performance issue then.

Comment: Right.  It's something with the way that the listview is working with the data.  It's just so slow.

Answer (score 7):

This ended up being an easy fix.  I added the following to the `ListView` declaration:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
```

It now looks like this:

```
    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FoundItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              MaxHeight="2000"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
```

My list went from taking at least a minute to load large lists, to almost instantaneous.